# how do you mock an imported enum with jasmine

Tags: angular, enums, mocking

I'm writing some jasmine tests for some existing code and can't find a way to mock an imported enum (to keep the test isolated). I'm trying to check the enum label looked up matches the one on the html page where expected.  I'm not interested in the actual looked up value, just that the label is on the page in the right page.

### Existing Code

**labels.service.ts**

```
export enum LabelEnum {
  common_Greeting,
  Common_ButtonClose,
  Common_ButtonSave
}

export LabelsService {
    public Get(enumLabelId: string): string {
        return "This would come from external API for content management";
    }
}
```

**some.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { LabelEnum, LabelsService } from "./labels.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './some.component.html',
  providers: [LabelsService]
})
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  greetingLabel: string;

  constructor(
    public labelsService: LabelsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.greetingLabel = this.labelsService.Get(LabelEnum.Common_Greeting);
  }
}
```

**some.component.html**

```
<div id="somePage">
  <div>
    <h1>{{greetingLabel}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Jasmine Test

**some.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { DebugElement, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LabelEnum, LabelsService } from "./labels.service";
import { SomeComponent } from "./some.component";

enum LabelEnumMock {
    Common_Greeting
}

class LabelsServiceStub {
    Get(id: string): string {
        return id;
    }
}

describe('SomeComponent', () => {
    let component: SomeComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<SomeComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;    
    let labelsService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [SomeComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: LabelsService, useClass: LabelsServiceStub },
                { provide: LabelEnum, useValue: LabelEnumMock }
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents()
            .then(() => {
                this.fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);              
                this.labelsService = this.fixture.debugElement.injector.get(LabelsService);
                this.el = this.fixture.nativeElement;
                this.de = this.fixture.debugElement;
            });
    }));

    afterEach(() => {
        this.fixture = null;        
        this.stringsService = null;
        this.el = null;
        this.de = null;
    });

    describe('after initialised', () => {       
        it('renders expected labels', () => {
            this.fixture.detectChanges();
            expect(this.el.querySelector('h1').innerText).toBe(LabelEnumMock.Common_Greeting);
        });
    });
});
```

I started to get a plunker of this working unfortunately it doesn't run.

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/gDeGiKGxcWe5BwujPUAX?p=preview).

Comment: If you want to `provide: LabelEnum` then it needs to *actually be being provided by DI*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enum doesn't work like this. We can compare an enum to an array with explicit name of key:

```
export enum LabelEnum {
  common_Greeting, 
  Common_ButtonClose,
  Common_ButtonSave
}
console.log(LabelEnum.common_Greeting) //=> 0 (it's a number not a string)
console.log(LabelEnum.Common_ButtonClose) //=> 1
console.log(LabelEnum.Common_ButtonSave) //=> 2
```

But you can assign value to your enum entries:

```
enum Direction {
    Up = "UP",
    Down = "DOWN",
    Left = "LEFT",
    Right = "RIGHT",
}
console.log(Direction.Up) //=> UP
console.log(Direction.Left) //=> LEFT
```

I think your label service is bad typed too, I propose:

```
export LabelsService {
    public Get(enumLabelId: LabelEnum): string {
        return enumLabelId;
    }
}
```

Personally, I don't take your way to test the service. I think I just test the return of get like:

```
it("Should return the converted value for common greeting label", () => {
   expect(labelsService.get(LabelEnum.common_Greeting)).toEqual(LabelEnum.common_Greeting)
})
```

In this case, it's not useful to mock and stub your code, because it's your own logic and not depend of third-part especially for the enum.

And in the angular component I just display the return of the Get

Comment: I agree, due to the enum being part of our essential integrity and not an independent service then there is no need to mock that.

Comment: After for the service, I advise you to use an interface to decouple your code

Comment: The scenario given is a bit of an abstraction from a legacy application with a new angular front end.  It's not really anything I can change, only add specs to.  My angle for the specs was primarily aimed at make sure the correct label is in the correct place and not the content of the label.  But yes your quite right ideally it should be decoupled and eventually will be :)